# Bitmap Factory throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-resources, android-bitmap

I am having a weird problem. I am trying to use a PNG file from my res/drawable folder within my Android project, and to use such a PNG file in a ImageButton (which has the method "setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)") I need to decode the PNG image which I have in my res/drawable file. However, when I copy the path and try to decode it like such:

```
public Bitmap getBitMap() {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile("drawable/bishop00.png");
}
```

I saw some threads that said that I could also use the "decodeResources" method of BitmapFactory, but this code is not in an activity, and I do not wish to use an activity as a parameter to just use that method, seeing as this should work. I have also tried using the absolute path to this (copying the path which shows the entire hierarchy of my system) but I still get the following exception:

```
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

Really hope to get some help, seeing as I am completely sure the file exists.

Comment: Does the file drawable/bishop00.png exist on your phone?

Comment: No, I am trying to decode it from my android project (which I said in the original post) and then display it in my application

Comment: I fixed the title of the question. There's nothing weird about throwing `FileNotFoundException`. The file doesn't exist and the exception is throw

Comment: Resources in your app are not files in the actual app (even though they're files in the project), hence when you try to open one as a file it tells you there's no such file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to use a PNG file from my res/drawable folder within my Android project

That is a file on your development machine. It is not a file on the Android device.

> seeing as this should work

No, it should not.

> I saw some threads that said that I could also use the "decodeResources" method of BitmapFactory

That is the correct answer, assuming that this content should be a drawable resource in the first place. While there are some valid reasons for using `decodeResource()`, it is not that commonly used overall. There may be other ways of using the drawable resource that are more appropriate, or perhaps this should not be a drawable resource in the first place.

> but this code is not in an activity

`decodeResource()` takes a `Context`. It does not have to be an `Activity`, though that usually is a likely candidate. All of your code is executed along some code path that started with a `Context`; you should have no problems having one for use here.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Do you have any other suggestions than using "decodeResources"?

Comment: @tomSurge The suggestion is to use decodeResources.

Comment: @tomSurge: I cannot readily answer that, without knowing what it is that you are trying to do overall. What are you intending to do with the `Bitmap`?

Comment: @CommonsWare I am basically making a chess application. Each of the piece objects has a getBitmap function that should return a bitmap of their corresponding piece. For instance, I want to use the image of this bitmap on my ImageButton by doing setBitMap(piece.getBitmap);

Catch my drift?

Comment: @tomSurge: Well, off the cuff, I would replace `getBitmap()` with `getDrawableId()` or something like that, which returns the `R.drawable.` value for the piece. Then, [use `setImageResource()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)) to apply it to the `ImageButton`. That would be faster and use less memory.

Comment: Thank-you! Will try it out! Appreciate the help :)